# Oracle multiplexing redo log

Tags: oracle, logging, multiplexing, redo

I have 5 redo log files on the same disk as below :

```
/disk1/oradata/redo01.log

/disk1/oradata/redo02.log

/disk1/oradata/redo03.log

/disk1/oradata/redo04.log

/disk1/oradata/redo05.log
```

But it is advisable to multiplex on another disk. In this case, I want to set up the following procedure in SQL:

```
alter database add logfile member /disk2/oradata/redo01_b.log

alter database add logfile member /disk2/oradata/redo02_b.log

alter database add logfile member /disk2/oradata/redo03_b.log

alter database add logfile member /disk2/oradata/redo04_b.log

alter database add logfile member /disk2/oradata/redo05_b.log

alter system set log_archive_dest_2 = "LOCATION = /disk2/oradata/" SCOPE = BOTH;
```

But I do not know if it's worth it, if it's the best method and what's the consequence on my database.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to duplicate the recording to the second disk, if the second disk is an independent device, and not a partition on the first disk.
Writing transaction logs to disk2 will increase disk2 load.

```
ALTER DATABASE ADD LOGFILE MEMBER '/disk2/oradata/redo01_b.log' TO GROUP 1;
ALTER DATABASE ADD LOGFILE MEMBER '/disk2/oradata/redo02_b.log' TO GROUP 2;
ALTER DATABASE ADD LOGFILE MEMBER '/disk2/oradata/redo03_b.log' TO GROUP 3;
ALTER DATABASE ADD LOGFILE MEMBER '/disk2/oradata/redo04_b.log' TO GROUP 4;
ALTER DATABASE ADD LOGFILE MEMBER '/disk2/oradata/redo05_b.log' TO GROUP 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dmitry. 
I will put this in place.